# How can I read data from excel file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I know there is a code for readind text files like:

```
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        return lines
```

Is there a way to do the same with excel files (without importing pandas).
And another question: if i import pandas, can I use it not only for csv files, but also for excel files?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html